# What does "If you play with them frequently, something good may happen" mean?

Tags: world-of-goo

What does the game mean exactly with this sentence from the World of Goo corporation description?

Full description, for reference:

> ## World of Goo Corporation
>
> Goo balls you collect in each level get sent here. If you play with them frequently, something good may happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's an actual meaning behind it. A lot of things in World of Goo are put in just for the humour with not much real meaning. Maybe if you try often enough, you'll score high?

Answer (score 4):

I think the only thing that happens is that if you build a high tower you can see up to three funny advertising signs (at least after chapter 4). You'll also see clouds showing other players current tower height if you clicked on the `connect` button.